# AWS S3 - Unable to save file using getObject() with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm relatively new to using AWS and am stuck on what I believe should be a basic task.  I'm using the PHP SDK version 2 to retrieve files from one of my buckets to a temp directory on my server.  According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObject) I can use **getObject** to do this.  Using the following code snippets I am able to retrieve the file but am having trouble saving the actual contents to the temp directory.

**#1**

```
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    "Bucket" => $s3Bucket,
    "Key"    => $s3Path,
    "ResponseContentType" => "image/jpeg",
    "SaveAs" => EntityBody::factory(fopen($saveFile, "wb"))
));
```

**#2**

```
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    "Bucket" => $s3Bucket,
    "Key"    => $s3Path,
    "ResponseContentType" => "image/jpeg",
    "SaveAs" => fopen($saveFile, "wb")
));
```

Both of these request are successful in the sense that they return the object but I am still getting a tmp file of 0 bytes.  Any insight into this is greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3091dWHz91qzqo4po1_400.jpg

Comment: Have you evaluated your response from the API call to see if you are getting any errors (i.e. what do you get when you `var_dump($result)`)?

Comment: There didn't appear to be any errors returned.  I ended up scrapping this approach and just grabbing the files via CURL as there are publicly available.  Frustrating though.

Comment: I think using `wb` and the `fopen` options may be causing the issue

Answer (score 8):

You can try

```
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

$s3Client->getObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $s3Bucket,
  'Key'    => $s3Path,
  'command.response_body' => EntityBody::factory(fopen($saveFile, 'w+'))
));
```

Also

```
$result = $s3Client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $s3Bucket,
    'Key'    => $s3Path
));

file_put_contents ($saveFile, (string) $result['Body']);
```

Comment: I'm not doing a question but I appreciate your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Amazon Bucket and Key are correct. I got this error and discovered that the path to the AWS object was incorrect which means the file is created but no data is written to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObject)

```
$s3Client->getObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $s3Bucket,
  'Key'    => $s3Path,
  'SaveAs' => $filePath
));
```